# A plugin popularity data inside "install new plugin"

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

Where i can find a plugin that can show in WordPress `/wp-admin/plugin-install.php` the download count of each plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Mark Jaquith wrote a plugin a while back that fetches data from plugins on the WordPress repo, i'd suggest taking a look at this plugin's code to get some ideas about how to query the WordPress Repository API, it's not a huge plugin so you should be able to pluck the necessary info from the main plugin file quite easily, a link to the source is posted below.

**Source for main plugin file**
http://svn.wp-plugins.org/i-make-plugins/trunk/i-make-plugins.php

**Plugin home page**
http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/new-plugin-i-make-plugins/

Notably the plugin API can return the download count for a given plugin.

Comment: @:t3los, How did you find  these plugin in trunk? any specialized keyword in Google for this one?

Comment: Simply goto `http://svn.wp-plugins.org/plugin-slug/` where `plugin-slug` is the slug of the given plugin..

Comment: @:t3los: Thanks for your information.it's very useful to find the plugin's. +1 for your reply:)-